# T-SQL CASE Statement without overlapping criteria test

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Since the following code prints 'First' and 'Second' INSERT that order, can I conclude that the first condition satisfied is ALWAYS executed?

```
DECLARE @Constant1 int = 1
DECLARE @Constant2 int = 2

select 
     case 
          when @Constant1 = 1 
               then 'First'
          when @Constant1 = 1  and @Constant2 = 2
               then 'Second'               
     end as Result

select 
     case 
          when @Constant1 = 1  and @Constant2 = 2
               then 'Second'                    
          when @Constant1 = 1 
               then 'First'

     end as Result
```

I know that sometimes parallel processing effects the outcome and I was trying to understand IF this type of situation that I see in Production would always return the same result.

This question is intended to understand if there is a potential issue in production code. If I were going to write the code anew, I think I would try to make the code explicitly mutually exclusive..

```
select 
     case 
          when @Constant1 = 1 and @Constant2 != 2
               then 'First'

          when @Constant1 = 1  and @Constant2 = 2
               then 'Second'                    

     end as Result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Documentation for [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) states.

> **Searched CASE expression:**
>
> - Evaluates, in the order specified, Boolean_expression for each WHEN clause.
> - Returns result_expression of the first Boolean_expression that evaluates to TRUE.
> - If no Boolean_expression evaluates to TRUE, the Database Engine returns the else_result_expression if an ELSE clause is specified, or
>     a NULL value if no ELSE clause is specified.

So it will return the first true branch.

For a simple query such as in the question I would expect it to not evaluate the other branches either.

A few cases where this short circuiting behaviour does not work as expected/advertised are discussed in this DBA site question.

[Does SQL Server read all of a COALESCE function even if the first argument is not NULL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no/12943#12943)

But just to be clear these issues do not affect the left to right precedence order of the result (except for the case when evaluating a later branch causes an error to occur such that no result is returned at all)